# How to delete previous revisions with svn?

Tags: svn, svnserve

I want to clear all all previous revisions and leave only the current revision.

Is there a way to do this?

I don't find a possible command to do this:

```
[secret@vps303 ~]# svnadmin --help
general usage: svnadmin SUBCOMMAND REPOS_PATH  [ARGS & OPTIONS ...]
Type 'svnadmin help <subcommand>' for help on a specific subcommand.
Type 'svnadmin --version' to see the program version and FS modules.

Available subcommands:
   crashtest
   create
   deltify
   dump
   help (?, h)
   hotcopy
   list-dblogs
   list-unused-dblogs
   load
   lslocks
   lstxns
   pack
   recover
   rmlocks
   rmtxns
   setlog
   setrevprop
   setuuid
   upgrade
   verify
```

**UPDATE**

Seems the only solution is to export then import, but will the access permission settings be also exported when we run `svn export` ?

Comment: Why don't you want to checkout current revision and then create new repository for it?

Comment: That would be better, but is it possible with zendstudio? I don't find a menu to create a repository with zendstudio.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is indeed to

```
svnadmin dump -r<revisionnumber> /old/repo/path > repo.dmp
svnadmin create /new/repo/path
svnadmin load  /new/repo/path <  repo.dmp
```

Do *not* use `svn export`, you might loss some handy svn:externals, svn:ignore's, svn:executable and the like. Older revisions & logging OK, but those you normally want to keep :)

Possible auth/access/hook/other configuration you can usually copy by copying the ./conf & ./hooks directories from the old repository to the new one. As long as there are no hardcoded paths in it those should work instantly. After copying those dirs do compare the file premissions of your old & new repo.

Use the svnadmin bin on the svn-server, you cannot do this with an svn client.

Comment: I don't exactly get the difference between `svn export` and `svnadmin dump`, it seems to me the only difference is that `svn export` will create recursive subdirectories if necessary, while `svnadmin dump` will store all the information in a single file?

Comment: With `export` you will LOSE ALL SVN SETTINGS, with `dump` you will lose only the specific changes per revision & the revisionnumbers (up to the number you give, for instance, you could keep revisions 123 to 128, which would be 1 to 5 on import), which you can load directly into another repository.

Comment: I just made a test, with `dump` the settings in `conf/passwd` and `conf/svnserve.conf` aren't dumped,say,they're also LOST, right?

Comment: OK, authorisation/server settings are not preserved, but file settings in svn are. Then again, if you never have done any propsetting/ignoring of files you wouldn't see a difference. Most of my projects are so modular I'd hate to have svn:external's forgotten, let alone setting back all svn:executable's.